# Alexa skill Interaction Model unsure about custom slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I brought an Amazon echo in hope to have it send commands to my HTPC. 
I found and set up the following which uses alexa with eventghost.

http://www.eventghost.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7429&sid=c3d48a675d6d5674b25a35f4850bc920

The original poster used *"literal"* in the skill intent which I found doesn't work anymore. After reading through the whole thread I saw you need to create a custom slot type.

here is the skill set up

**Intent scheme**

```
{
  "intents": [ {
      "intent": "Run",
   "slots": [
     {
       "name": "Action",
       "type": "Commands"
     } ]
  } ]
}
```

**Custom Slot Types**

*Commands*

```
cleanup
clean up
move movies
move downloads
move cartoons
move the cartoons
move the downloads
move the downloaded movies
play
pause
stop
```

**Sample Utterances**

```
Run {Action}
```

What I'm wanting to do is say:
"Alexa tell/ask (Invocation Name) to clean up" 
or 
"Alexa tell/ask (Invocation Name) to Move movies"

I typed in the custom slot to what I believe is the correct format based on my web searching.

the problem is when I run it through Alexa it sometimes hits Eventghost slightly wrong.

how can I fine tune it. or do i have the skill set up wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above Setup Looks fine, Alexa skill has ability learn by training Skill more

But I dont know, you made typo error

Your Sample Utterances looks like "Alexa tell/ask (Invocation Name) clean up", but your ask as "Alexa tell/ask (Invocation Name) ***to*** clean up" with extra word as "to", if this is not an typo error, please remove word "to"

Because while pronunciation, the word "to" will try to combine with your commands

Comment: Many thanks yes 'to' was a typo in my post my prompt is  "Alexa tell/ask (Invocation Name) clean up"